# 'Make sound lower' button on my Lenovo z570 got stucked

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

'Make sound lower' button on my Lenovo z570 got stucked. How can I repair the demage?

I'm not sure if it can be hooked cause its edges are very close to the keyboard lid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't be afraid to use Google before asking the question.
Service manual for your model of laptop can be found [here](http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User%27s%20guides%20and%20manuals/Z370&Z470&Z570/Lenovo%20Z370Z470Z570%20Hardware%20Maintenance%20Manual%20V1.0.pdf). This manual contains detailed instructions on how to disassemble your laptop. This should be enough to repair or replace damaged button. Good luck